# Comma between two questions after introductory clause

Tags: punctuation

Should there be a comma between two independent questions that follow an introductory clause:

So when you arrived, was Mr. Smith still in his vehicle or was he out of the vehicle?

-or-

So when you arrived, was Mr. Smith still in his vehicle, or was he out of the vehicle?

Answers with references are greatly appreciated!

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

This is really a question of style, not grammar.  While grammar does call for a comma before a coordinating conjunction (i.e., and, or, nor, for, but, yet, so) when it introduces a coordinate clause, like it does in your example, grammar also allows said comma to be eliminated when the preceding main clause is short.  While "short" is a rather vague term, few would argue that the preceding main clause in your example isn't short.  That means the comma in this case is optional, so it becomes a question of style, not grammar.

https://owl.english.purdue.edu/owl/resource/607/2/

https://writing.wisc.edu/Handbook/CoordConj.html